# numpy.linalg.det returns very small numbers instead of 0

Tags: python, numpy

I calculated the determinant of matrix using `np.linalg.det(matrix)` but it returns weird values. For example, it gives 1.1012323e-16 instead of 0.

Of course, I can round the result with `numpy.around`, but is there any option to set some "default" rounding for results of all numpy methods, including `numpy.linalg.det`?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the determinant looking "weird" is due to the floating point arithmetic, you can look it up.
Regarding your question, I believe `numpy.set_printoptions` is what you are looking for. Please, see [Docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)